Why aren't template parameters considered constant expressions (for consteval)?
I would like to use consteval functions to perform computations on template parameters at compile time, so that my operations result in immediates that don't incur any performance penalty. For example:
// Changing this to constexpr will cause the function
// to be invoked at runtime.
consteval int abs(int x) {
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

template <int N>
struct Test {
    bool isValid(int y) {
        return y < abs(N); // Error.
    }
};

I used consteval so that abs(N) would be replaced with an immediate value rather than calling the function at runtime (as would happen if abs() were constexpr). For example, within the body of Test<7>::isValid(), I would think abs(7) resolves to 7 and does not need to be calculated at runtime. However, this code produces the following error:

Call to consteval function 'abs' is not a constant expression ... subexpression not valid in a constant expression [invalid_consteval_call]

(tested in clang 17.0.6). This error still occurs if you attempt to define a static constexpr variable based on N:
// Changing this to constexpr works though!
consteval int abs(int x) {
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

template <int N>
struct Test {
    static constexpr int ABS_N = abs(N); // Error

    bool isValid(int y) {
        return y < ABS_N;
    }
};

The funny part is, if you change abs() from consteval to constexpr in this version, then the generated code uses an immediate like I wanted! On the other hand, templates can be used with consteval to achieve the same goal:
template <int X>
consteval int abs() {
    return X < 0 ? -X : X;
}

template <int N>
struct Test {
    bool isValid(int y) {
        return y < abs<N>();
    }
}

I also noticed that using a static constexpr variable instead of a template parameter works, although here it's pretty easy to see why:
struct Test {
    static constexpr int N = 7;

    bool isValid(int y) {
        return y < abs(N);
    }
}

Why are template parameters not allowed to be passed to consteval functions?

function parameters aren't constant expressions.  If they were then you could make a function that returns different types depending on the value of the parameter.  That is not something the language can support.

Please post a minimal reproducible example. The template at the beginning compiled fine with all the compilers I tried and I could call isValid().

Why is parameter not a constant expression? and Use of consteval function parameters in a static_assert and Will consteval functions allow template parameters dependent on function arguments?

duplicates are about using a function parameter as template argument. This question is about the opposite

@463035818_is_not_an_ai That doesn't change the fact that function parameters like x in consteval int abs(int x);  aren't constant expressions.

@user12002570 "why aren't template parameters ..." vs "function parameters like x ... aren't constant expressions" one is about template parameters the other about function parameters. In the course of this question there is also a case about function paramters, but the initial code and question is about template parameter used to call a function

It seems like my build system was using the system installed version of clang (14.0.0) rather than the one I installed via Homebrew. Compiling manually with clang 18.1.4 (after I upgraded) worked fine. Thanks to @Cem for testing out different compiler versions and pointing me in the right direction!

Your issue seems in fact be a name conflict:
(non consteval) abs from C header conflicting with your abs.
Renaming your function solves the issue:
consteval int my_abs(int x) {
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

template <int N>
struct Test {
    static constexpr int ABS_N = my_abs(N); // OK
    bool isValid(int y) {
        return y < my_abs(N); // OK
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<42>().isValid(0);
}

Demo

If it was a conflicting definition, it wouldn't work when changing consteval to constexpr, though. Would it?

It doesn't for me...  We state that what OP wants is possible, but not succeeded to reproduce OP's exact issue.

Your consteval function has undefined behavior if x is INT_MIN (aka: std::numeric_limits<int>::min()).
This code fixes it:
#include <limits>
consteval int abs(const int x) {
    if (x == std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

With that change alone, I was unable to replicate your error on clang (trunk = 18.1.0 on x64).
However, your isValid() method should probably be static, or at the very least const, ie:
#include <limits>

consteval int abs(const int x) {
    if (x == std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

template <int N>
struct Test {
    static constexpr int ABS_N = abs(N); // Should be fine.

    static constexpr bool isValid(const int y) noexcept {
        return y < ABS_N;
    }
};

Live on Compiler Explorer

but why does the code also compile without errors without your fix applied ? https://godbolt.org/z/fYhjGoKeW

Oh, yeah. Forgot to say what the fix was. consteval (or constexpr) makes invoking the function a constant expression. The check for overflow makes the code valid even if the function is constexpr (undefined behavior is not allowed with consteval)
